# Mule WMQ Connection not spreading across Queue Manager

Tags: jms, mule, ibm-mq, mule-component, mule-esb

We have build an Mule applications with 1 mule nodes and 2 WMQ Manager. We are using HA proxy to route the traffic to multiple queue manager.(in properties file, we specify queuemanager = * )

Though we create multiple connections from Mule, all the connections are going to the same queue manager.( lets say, I keep numberofConsumer = 16 ) all the 16 connections are going to the same queue manager.

Did anyone encountered this issue? any work around. Composite component solves this issue but composite element is not in mule 4.

I am using the IBM jar. com.ibm.mq.allclient-8.0.0.3.jar. I am using the below connection factory and MQ Connector Factory

```
<wmq:connector name="drs-Request" port="${drs.mq.port}" transportType="CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP" specification="1.1" targetClient="JMS_COMPLIANT" validateConnections="true" maxRedelivery="-1" numberOfConsumers="${drs.mq.no.of.consumers}"  connectionFactory-ref="drsConnectionFactory" doc:name="WMQ">
    <reconnect-forever blocking="false" frequency="${drs.mq.reconnection.frequency}"/>
</wmq:connector>             
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="drsConnectionFactory" name="drsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
        <spring:property name="channel" value="${drs.mq.channel}"/>
        <spring:property name="hostName" value="${drs.mq.hostname}"/>
        <spring:property name="port" value="${drs.mq.port}"/>
        <spring:property name="queueManager" value="${drs.mq.queuemanager}"/>
        <spring:property name="transportType" value="1"/>
        <spring:property name="sSLCipherSuite" value="${drs.mq.ciphersuite}"/>
    </spring:bean>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try setting `SHARECNV(1)` on your `SVRCONN` channel, this would at least cause a new channel per connection, but i'm unsure if in this context if it would still be connecting to the same IP.  By default SHARECNV(10), but even with that setting when you get above 10 connections you should have started a second instance. When you state that you use a HA proxy is this like a F5 LTM or GTM device?  Is it IP (LTM) or DNS (GTM) based load balancing?  If DNS based perhaps mule is caching the result of the DNS query?  If IP based check for stickyness settings on the HA proxy.

Comment: Thanks. we are using HA proxy to load balancing the back end. It's IP based. Changing to ShareCNV(1) did not help as you said.